# Right derived functor and composition

Tags: category-theory

Let $G:\mathscr{C}\to \mathscr{D}$ and $F:\mathscr{D}\to \mathscr{E}$ be functors, and suppose $F$ is right exact. It makes sense to me that in this case we have
$$ R^i(F\circ G) \cong F \circ R^iG $$
where $R^i\square$ denotes the $i$-th right derived functor of $\square$.

Is this correct? If so, how can one prove this? If not, what is a counter-example?

Comment: It looks like you have some typoes of symbols -- I think you mean, on the right hand side of your formula, to be putting the $R^i$ next to the functor that's not right-exact (else that $R^i$ is zero, of course). Also, note that you need to require $G$ to take injective objects to $F$-acyclic objects to make sense of the statement.

Comment: Oh thanks, about your first remark: it was indeed a typo, now corrected. About the second: I believe you, but let me think about it for a moment

Comment: That is correct. You should noy thave any problem proving from the definition of derived functors, really. Why don't we do it this way, instead: you write your attempt and we can help you with it? :-)

Comment: @hunter: I'm sorry, I don't understand why we need that assumption on $G$. Could you explain please?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Ok, nice! I'm going to the swimming pool right now (the time table is strict!) but I will try to do it later in case nobody answered yet. Promise! ;-)

Comment: @hunter, that hypothesis is needed to build the Grothendieck spectral sequence, but with the assumption that F is exact there is no need for it.

Comment: @mariano you are right. In fairness, $G$ was exact when I made that comment!

Comment: Ah. That does change things :-)

Comment: Urgh. In fact, I misread this.  My comment above was made with the idea that $F$ was supposed to be **exact**. If it is only right exact, then this does not work and you do neeed the whole spectral sequence!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is such an isomorphism. Maybe under the reasonable assumption is that $\mathcal{C}$ has enough injectives.

You can prove it using $\delta$-functors. Note that $F\circ R^iG$ has a natural structure of $\delta$-functor. To see this, when given a short exact sequence $0\rightarrow A'\rightarrow A\rightarrow A''\rightarrow 0$, you get a long exact sequence with the $R^iG(A)$s, then apply $F$ which is exact.

To prove it is universal, it is sufficient to show that it vanishes on injectives for $i>0$, but this is the case since $R^iG$ vanishes on injective. So $F\circ R^iG$ is the $i$-th derived functor of $F\circ R^0G=F\circ G$.

Comment: $F$ is ony *right* exact.

Comment: Oh, ok. mmh, does it makes sense to speak about $R^i(F\circ G)$ then ?

Answer (score 1):

See

W.W.Adams, M.A.Rieffel, Adjoint functors and derived functors with an application to the cohomology of semigroups. J. Algebra, v.7(1967), N1, pp.25-34.

Comment: Thanks Boris, this is closely related. Unfortunately in Proposition 1 they require as an hypothesis $F$ to be exact and not only right exact.

Comment: @Abramo: Yes, it is not a complete answer. But I hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Yes, actually it is very useful even in that form, but for a different problem I was trying to solve. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Abramo: You are welcome.